# Find out internal OpenShift registry IP or URL

Tags: docker, registry, okd

I set up an OpenShift cluster using *oc cluster up*. Now I want to directly access the internal registry, but I am not able to find out the correct url. I already searched a lot for this, but it seems that all the potential solutions don´t point me to the correct way to find out.
I was hoping there´s something like *docker-registry.:5000* but I get a connection refused when using it for docker login.
I already tried:

```
docker login -u developer -p "$(oc whoami -t)" docker-registry.<hostname>:5000
docker login -u developer -p "$(oc whoami -t)" registry.<hostname>:5000
docker login -u developer -p "$(oc whoami -t)" <hostname>:5000
```

Can you help me?

Kind regards

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I found out by myself:
I had to login as admin using *oc login -u system:admin*. Then I got the registry IP by switching to the default namespace and getting the services:

```
oc project default
oc get svc
```

which gave my the following output:

```
NAME              TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                   AGE
docker-registry   ClusterIP   172.30.1.1       <none>        5000/TCP                  9m
kubernetes        ClusterIP   172.30.0.1       <none>        443/TCP,53/UDP,53/TCP     9m
router            ClusterIP   172.30.100.230   <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP,1936/TCP   9m
```

I was then able to login using docker:

```
docker login -u developer -p "$(oc whoami -t)" 172.30.1.1:5000
```

Hope this helps anybody